# Elevated viewpoint to photograph Burj Khalifa, Dubai

Tags: dubai, viewpoint

*[Asked on PSE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86754/elevated-viewpoint-to-see-dubai-burj-khalifa) earlier but it was suggested to me more likely to be answered here and I think so too.*

There are a number of amazing photos of the Burj Khalifa which are seemingly taken from an elevated viewpoint. It is possible that some are taken by drone although, I'm not sure drones can get that high at all. What I am looking for a publicly accessible location which would be open until past sunset to take pictures of Dubai with the Burj Khalifa nicely visible.

**Which elevated publicly-accessible locations exist to take photos of the Burj Khalifa?**

Here are some Google Image Search results that have a desirable viewpoint. I would really like to find the viewpoint for the first one as it is most appealing to me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Agree with @pnuts. Dubai is very flat (this is also pretty obvious from photos). Those photos are definitely taken from air.

Comment: Only if you have a drone with a camera which, btw, are illegal in Dubai

Comment: So are all these illegal photos?!

Comment: There are plenty of helicopter tours around Dubai

Comment: @JonathanReez - That wouldn't work for the first image and plenty more found online. The light trails we see of vehicles implies and exposure of several seconds which would not be possible from a helicopter. Not sure how stable a drone is but I would be surprised if it was sufficiently stable.

Comment: @GeorgeY - Aren't they any other observations decks or rooftop venues in another sky-scraper in Dubai?

Comment: They are - you can see them on the first photo - but for the first photo you're looking for something at least as tall as Burj Khalifa. I'm looking on my photos there, and nothing is even close to that.

Comment: @GeorgeY. - Do those observation location have names? So that I can look them up. I've been trying but no luck so far. Other than the middle photo, they would only need to be half-as-tall as the Burj Khalifa, but at this point I won't be picky if it's shorter than that :)

Comment: Emirates Towers I've been to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first picture was taken from The Address Downtown Dubai hotel. This is the one that suffered a major fire event at the beginning of 2016. It is currently being renovated so no chance to get there right now.

The second one was definitely taken from an helicopter or a drone.

The third one was most likely taken from the Taj hotel.

I believe a high viewpoint could also be from the JW Marriott Marquis hotel (355 meters).

You can find there the list of buildings in Dubai :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_buildings_in_Dubai

Comment: It was indeed the address. Not many buildings offer such a view. Nearly all other potential ones were being built or privately owned. The Emirates Towers someone suggested were too far to get a clear view.

Answer (score 3):

[Helidubai](http://www.helidubai.com/) offers scenic tours as well as aerial filming from helicopter.